# Accidentally deleted `.cabal/` under `$HOME`. Now HLS does not work

Tags: haskell, cabal

So I have installed some library with `cabal install --lib`, which as I have realized is not a great idea. While trying to undo it, I ended up deleting .cabal, thinking it would just get regenerated. Since I definitely did not manually create that folder, there should be a way to get it to generate. What would be the way to do that?

I am getting an error on the first line of my Haskell programs saying this:

```
ghcide compiled by GHC 8.10 failed to load packages: haskell-language-server-8.10.7: can't find a package database at /home/kintrix/.cabal/store/ghc-8.10.7/package.db. 
Please ensure that ghcide is compiled with the same GHC installation as the project.cradle
```

So I assume it is related to the .cabal directory missing.

I have tried reinstalling Cabal, GHC, HLS, or GHCup all together. None of them regenerated it/solved the error.

Comment: You could try `cabal update`. I'm not sure if that works but it might.

Comment: can you try building something with cabal `cabal build <some-project>` so you download the libraries again

Comment: `cabal update` should be enough, although it sounds like a poor UX that should be filed either on HLS bug tracker or on cabal's one. Both projects are hosted on GitHub under the haskell organization.